# Angular 7 fullpage.js and AOS

Tags: angular, animation, fullpage.js

My problem is the next. I use full page JS via angular.json, and try to use AOS library same time. I would like to use fade-up and other effects. On the first page it is working well. If I put data-os="fade-up" attribute to to actual element on second page, it will be hidden. How can I solve this problem, that fullpage.js and AOS works together ?

**app.component.html:**

```
 app-header></app-header>
<div class="fullpage">
<div mnFullpage>

    <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table">
      <div class="fp-tableCell">
        <app-welcome-component></app-welcome-component>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table">
      <div class="fp-tableCell">   
            <app-about></app-about>
            <app-technology></app-technology>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table">
      <div class="fp-tableCell">  
            <app-theory></app-theory>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table">
        <div class="fp-tableCell">
            <app-needs></app-needs>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table">
            <div class="fp-tableCell">
                <app-commercial></app-commercial>
            </div>
          </div>

</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as AOS from 'aos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ltd-site';

  ngOnInit(){
    AOS.init({

    })
    AOS.refresh();
  }
}
```

On the first component the  tag works well. (On my first "landing"-page ) But if I scroll the next one, it doesn't works.

Can somebody point me what causes the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Use the fullpage.js option `scrollBar:true`
- Or make use of [fullpage.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) or [state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) to fire your animations. 
  I made a video tutorial about state classes for css animations `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M`.

Also, in case you are not using it already, note there's an [Angular component for fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/angular-fullpage/).